# What is Meta for?

Tags: discussion, meta

I [recently asked here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343212/can-one-ask-how-to-build-a-chair-i-saw-on-the-web) if I could ask a certain type of DIY question. It received a score of -3 and was eventually closed.

My question: isn't the purpose of Meta to make sure that I ask correct questions in SE?

Comment: But you didn't ask **where** you could ask a DIY question, you just asked a DIY question straight off. If you'd asked "where can I ask the following question..." you'd have got a different result.

Comment: It's not a _DIY_ question. It's a question about a chair that a novice `Do It Yourself`guy wants to try.

Comment: You've missed the point. Whatever the question you need to phrase it as "where would I ask.." and not just launch into it. On top of that you called it a 'DIY question" above.

Answer (score 15):

Each site in the network has its own per-site meta, e.g. https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/. That's the correct place to ask whether you could ask a certain type of question on *that specific site*, and it turns out you already did: [Can I ask how to build a chair I saw on the web?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1489/56858). Those questions are off-topic here, because we really can't answer that; there might be some users here who are familiar with DIY.SE, but they are few and far between.

A similar type of question which *is* on-topic for Meta Stack Exchange are so-called 'site recommendations'. If you need help to find the right Stack Exchange site for your question, you can ask here and tag your question [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation). We'll try to do our best to find the right site, but our opinions by no means guarantee that the question will be welcomed there.

Comment: Besides, there's good [tag:site-recommendation] questions and bad ones. Just because something is on-topic doesn't make it a good question.